# $\forall x(P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))\stackrel{?}{\equiv}\neg\exists x(P(x) \rightarrow \neg Q(x))\stackrel{?}{\equiv}\neg\exists x(P(x) \wedge\neg Q(x))$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Statement $1$: The statement $\forall x(P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$ reads "For all $x$, if $P(x)$, then $Q(x)$".

Statement $2$: The statement $\neg\exists x(P(x) \rightarrow \neg Q(x))$ reads "There does not exist an $x$ such that if $P(x)$, then not $Q(x)$".

Statement $3$: The statement $\neg\exists x(P(x) \wedge \neg Q(x))$ reads "There does not exist an $x$ such that $P(x)$ and not $Q(x)$".

When I think about these statements by only considering their meaning, I can't seem to come up with any distinctions between their meaning. I can use De Morgan's Law to show that statements $1$ and $3$ are logically equivalent. However, I am unable to show that statement $2$ is equivalent to the other two.

Could someone explain the difference in the meaning between statement $2$ and the other statements, perhaps with an example?

Comment: Because it is not... 2 is equiv to $\forall x ¬(P(x)→¬Q(x))$ i.e. to  $\forall x (P(x) \land Q(x))$ while 3 is $\forall x¬(P(x)∧¬Q(x))$ i.e. $\forall x (¬P(x) \lor Q(x))$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I understand that it is not equivalent, but I was wondering what is the difference in the meaning between statement 2 and the other statements. To me, the statements seem to be saying the saying thing.

Answer (score 2):

We can work with the different equivalent transformations of the formulas.

We agree that 1 and 3 are equivalent and 3 says that "there is no object $a$ such that $P(a)$ and $\lnot Q(a)$".

But this is consistent with: "for some $b$, $\lnot P(b)$ and $Q(b)$".

Consider 2 now: it is equivalent to  $¬∃x(¬P(x) \lor ¬Q(x))$ and to $∀x(P(x) ∧ Q(x))$

But this is **not** consistent with "for some $b$, $\lnot P(b)$ and $Q(b)$".

---

*Example*: 1 may be "for every x, if x is Male, than it is Human" that is the same as "there is no x that is Male and not Human", which is True.

Thus, 2 will be "there is no x such that if x is Male, than x is not Human", which is False because it amounts to "for every x, x is a Male and it is Human" (there are Women).

Comment: Although this technically answers my question, it doesn't illustrate the semantic difference between statement 2 and statement 3. However, the answer is helpful, so I have upvoted.